# Plotting lines in C++

Tags: c++, graphics

I have code to solve 2D truss structures implemented in C++ (as a console application).
I would like to add some simple graphics to it in order to visualize the initial structure and the deformed form. Example: http://people.rit.edu/pnveme/VenkatCOMSOL42/COMSOLTruss2D/ExtractingInfoinMATLAB_01.png

But I have no idea of how to add graphics in any way. How can I implement this kind of graphics?

---

Cross platform (preferred) or windows.

Comment: You need to specify the platform, as various 2D graphics options will be platform-specific.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is the answer you want, but to be honest, implementing plotting functionality isn't trivial, even if you're not doing it from scratch: you'll have to review a number of libraries, choose one, and get to grips with it.

Unless it's essential that the plotting functionality be integrated with the solver (e.g. for a product), I think you ought to consider simply exporting your results to, say, a simple ASCII matrix format that can be easily imported into a variety of environments with extensive and flexible plotting capabilities, one or more of which you probably already know (e.g. *Matlab*, *R*, *Octave*, etc.)

Comment: I agree 100%. Plotting is one of the single hardest things that applications commonly have to do, even though it seems like it should be 'trivial'.

Comment: @aruisdante: I'm going through the wringer myself on this one at the moment, and not for the first time :o(

Comment: I typically cheat and decouple the backend processing from the display, using something like boost::python to wrap the C++ processing side and then pyqt + pyplot or matplotlib to do the plotting from the returned processing data.

Comment: @aruisdante: I'm actually working in Python this time around. I have an implementation working with an embedded matplotlib widget, but I really don't like it much. What I'd really like is a QTableView-like QAbstractItemView subclass that's a wrapper around vtk or something, but I think my needs are probably too specific to find anything generic that I'll be happy with.

Answer (score 1):

Check out SDL: http://www.libsdl.org/ It's cross-platform and has a ton of features.  It maybe a bit overwhelming for your task, but I thought it was very easy to grasp when I was a newcomer.

There is a derivative of SDL that lets you draw basic shapes such as lines and points and is incredibly easy to use:

http://sdl-draw.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't think this is a very good suggestion for mathematical plotting. I don't know SDL very well, but it seems to me like almost any plotting-oriented library (e.g. GNU plotutils) would be a better fit.

Comment: @Emmet Could be.  You're a Stanford engineer, so I would assume you have better knowledge in this area.  I'm just recommending from personal experience.  I drew vectors with it. It's always nice to have a wide range of options, and it's just one recommendation among them.

Comment: Did you have to draw a multicolored 2D projection of a 3D object with scales, axis ticks, labels, and a title? Doing all that should be fairly trivial with a decent plotting API. Maybe that's all there in SDL, but, from what I've seen, I assume that it's a more general lower-level graphics library. I also wouldn't assume that I necessarily know what I'm talking about based on where I go to school :)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to generate a file which can be shown by another program. For example, generating SVG and using the browser to display it sounds like it would be good for your case, you can even easily include it in a report.